# Export a map into a useable format for a design software - QGIS?

Tags: qgis, design

I have a general map of the Mediterranean Sea, showing all the countries I've considered in a study, with watersheds etc. I've tried to make it look nice, but I think it could do with a bit of extra design. All the features in the map are contained in seperate shapefiles (countries, watersheds etc).

[image]

Is there a way to export this map, either in a shapefile format or using the print composer export types (PDF, SVG, image) so that it can be enhanced with a design software such as Indesign, Illustrator, or something similar? I'm no designer, just wandering if there is substance for improvement.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: The capabilities of QGIS have really improved through the years, so you can really accomplish a lot cartographically that you used to have to export to illustrator to achieve. I would suggest taking some more time to get your map to look good in QGIS before going down the road of exporting to a static file (no longer geographically aware) and touching it up in a graphics package.

Answer (score 1):

When u're in the layout designer you're able to **export your rendering in svg**. Most of the times (always ?) objects are scattered in differents layers so that the fine tuning of your map is not that hard in software like Inkscape ...
So what u're seeking in definitely possible with QGIS ... i don't know how will behave **raster parts** but all the other elements will be editable in vector softwares...